# How to change the ProgressDialog Message font size in android programmatically?

Tags: android, text, progressdialog

I have used progressDialog in my android application and i have used code as

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait to get contacts");
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);

        progressDialog.show();
```

I want to change the message font size and want to add  some color to the message is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(currentfile.this);

Dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='white'  ><big>"
                    + "Downloading ..." + "</big></font>"));

Dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make custom progress dialog like below:

custom_progress_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@null"
>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/string"
    android:size="30dp"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyCustomProgressDialog.java

```
public class MyCustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);

      ...
    }
    public static MyCustomProgressDialog ctor(Context context) {
        MyCustomProgressDialog dialog = new MyCustomProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }


     @Override
     public void show() {
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
      super.dismiss();
     }


}
```

and then use progress dialog class in asynctask like below:

```
class DemoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private final MyCustomProgressDialog progressDialog;

  public DemoAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
    progressDialog = MyCustomProgressDialog.ctor(ctx);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    progressDialog.show();
  }
```