# How to change the appearance of a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, customization

I know [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315413/how-to-change-the-progressdialog-message-font-size-in-android-programmatically), but I wonder why my solution does not work.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_text, null, false);
textView.setText(context.getResources().getString(msg));
dialog.setView(textView);
```

This is the layout custom_text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/messageSpinner"
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
```

The result is a window with the expected wheel but an empty message.

Comment: You change the view of dialog . Now whatever you put in that custom XML will appear on dialog i.e put a ProgresBar too

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the dialog view. Now the dialog only show your custom view. try adding progress bar also in your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar 
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"/>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/messageSpinner"
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dialog library : https://github.com/Samehadar/IOSDialog

It help you create Dialog easily.

[image]

I hope it wil help you.

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TransparentProgressDialog pd;
    private Handler h;
    private Runnable r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        h = new Handler();
        pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(this, R.drawable.spinner);
        r =new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        };
        findViewById(R.id.the_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pd.show();
        h.postDelayed(r,5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        h.removeCallbacks(r);
        if (pd.isShowing() ) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class TransparentProgressDialog extends Dialog {

        private ImageView iv;

        public TransparentProgressDialog(Context context, int resourceIdOfImage) {
            super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
            setTitle(null);
            setCancelable(false);
            setOnCancelListener(null);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            iv = new ImageView(context);
            iv.setImageResource(resourceIdOfImage);
            layout.addView(iv, params);
            addContentView(layout, params);
        }

        @Override
        public void show() {
            super.show();
            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            iv.setAnimation(anim);
            iv.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Transparent Progress Indicator" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check it out!"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/the_button" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!--  Transparent dialog -->
    <style name="TransparentProgressDialog" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**drawable/spinner.png**

[image]

**Output**

[image]